# Cycle through open desktops in Windows 10 automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, automation, external-display

I have a single display that I want to project information on for general public view but there is too much information to display all at once on a single screen. The java program I am using to display data is Swarm available through the USGS [ https://volcanoes.usgs.gov/software/swarm/download.shtml ]. Currently, I am using Swarm 3.2. This program allows displays of seismic data in several formats, and has some nice functions for simple displays. However, you cannot have multiple windows of the same "type" of data open in a single "kiosk" or instance of Swarm, and there is too many to display in a single window, and too many windows for a single screen. Although it has a Kiosk mode, it's meant for basic data displays and doesn't have a mode to cycle through open data windows.
My thinking was the best way to display this seismic data would be to create 2+ active desktops on my Windows 10 machine and shuffle between those desktops automatically every X seconds with the various programs/windows/GUI's open.  Is there a way to automate switching between these desktops **without active user input** (no shortcut / hot keys) and preferably no 3rd party software? If there is no way to automate this without 3rd party software, does anyone have a recommendation on software that I could use to do this task?

Another option might be related to cycle between specific open GUI's rather than switching desktops, but the number of open programs on a single desktop might not always be equal and I want the time between active desktops to be similar if possible. All options related to this idea have also required user input to switch between as well.

A potentially important note is the data displayed is not something that I can create as a background and then cycled through as a background or screen-saver style image as these displays are updated in real-time and are not static. Thus the need for these programs to be running while the display is active.

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: More info needed: what is the app displaying data, and why cannot it scroll through or select data screens?

Comment: The program is a java program "Swarm" available through the USGS. [https://volcanoes.usgs.gov/software/swarm/index.shtml]. This program allows displays of seismic data in several formats, and has some nice functions for simple displays.  However, you cannot have multiple windows of the same "type" of data open in a single "kiosk" or instance of Swarm, and there is too many to display in a single window, and too many windows for a single screen. Although it has a Kiosk mode, it's meant for basic data displays and doesn't have a mode to cycle through open data windows.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. Also, that link is invalid. Have you tried Swarm 3.2 to see if it meets your needs? https://volcanoes.usgs.gov/software/swarm/download.shtml

Comment: Updated, and the current version I am using is the latest release (3.2).